# What do comm and diff try to accomplish at input/output level?

Tags: text-processing, diff, version-control, math, comm

Given two files, for each line in each  file, how do [`comm`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#comm-invocation) and [`diff`](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#toc-diff-Output-Formats) determine

- whether the line also occur in the other file?
- if it does, whether its occurrences in the two files are the same or different?

by taking into account the order between the lines in each file?

How  does `diff` decide whether some line "occurs in both files but differ" or "occurs in one file but not the other"?

How do `comm` and `diff`  differ when both are used for taking subtraction of two files?

Thanks.

(just ignore the following if you are not interested in  some elementary mathematics. The above is self contained as far as my questions are concerned.)

---

**My guess:**

In mathematics, a set doesn't impose order between its elements. (if a set does, then it is called an ordered set, a different concept)

- "S1-S2", the set difference operation on two sets S1 and S2,  results in a set of the elements in the first set but not in the second.
- When taking the intersection of two sets, if an element is considered in both sets, it doesn't matter where it appears in each set.

Similar operations to set difference exist on files, such as [`comm` from coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#comm-invocation) and [`diff` from diffutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#toc-diff-Output-Formats).  But we can't think of a file as a set of lines, but as an ordered set of lines, because the lines are ordered by their line numbers naturally.

Moreover, `comm` and `diff` also work differently from each other.

What do `comm` and `diff` try to accomplish at concept level (at input and output level) respectively? If you can also use mathematics to explain, that might be clearer (I suspect I may need some basic knowledge on ordered sets). I don't expect an explanation at their implementation level, but that may help (some version control and backup software uses the same or similar algorithms for incremental copy).

Thanks.

Comment: With diff, it might be easier to start with the concept of a patch. A patch is a mathematical operation on a file. The diff command then asks, what patch will convert the first file into the second? So, diff is the inverse of patch.

Edit: also, you have a typo in the title, comm -> coom ;)

Comment: Have you tried studying the source code?  This is a detailed question, but have you done any research on your own?  If you want definitive knowledge, look at the source code; if approximations are acceptable, have you tried any reverse engineering?

Comment: @cry I get the rough idea of "diff" meaning subtraction of one file from the other. But at the line level, how does it make decision on each line?

Comment: @Wildcard: It is always much more difficult to deduce what a program tries to accomplish from its implementation. It is always much easier to know roughly what it tries to accomplish at first and then reads its implementation.

Comment: @Tim, that's true, but the comments in http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/tree/src/analyze.c seem like exactly what you want.  Not as high-level as it might be, perhaps, but also more likely to stay up to date as the program is modified, since the comments explaining intent are right next to the code that implements them.

Comment: You are mistaken, these programs are not from GNU. The diff(1) program was initially written by Douglas McIlroy at Bell Labs in 1974, comm(1) is from Lee E. McMahon from the same year.

Comment: @Wildcard: you are not talking about `diff`, but rather about `gdiff`. The recent `diff` sourcecode is here: https://sourceforge.net/p/schillix-on/schillix-on/ci/default/tree/usr/src/cmd/diff/ the algorithm used by `diff` is called `stone`. BTW: `gdiff` uses a different algorithm that is typically 30% slower and only wins, when the files are much larger than a megabyte, IIRC, you need 100MB files to make `gdiff` faster than `diff`.

Comment: @schily Tim explicitly linked to the GNU coreutils and diffutils; Wildcard never mentioned a program by name here, but linked to the GNU source code.

Comment: Well, if they did not mean `diff' but rather GNU diff, they could have used the orignal name `gdiff`.

Answer (score 2):

As noted here;
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff

> "The operation of diff is based on solving the longest common subsequence problem."

and as noted in the comments there are multiple implementations that differ slightly (diff,gdiff,vimdiff,git-diff,rdiff-backup,etc).
the wiki page on LCS has the mathimatical definition you ask for.
Subtract all the LCSs from the 2 orderd sets and a diff is the remainder.

Comment: Thanks. The LCS algorithm explains how diff decides if a line exists in one file but not in the other. How does diff decide whether a line occurs in both files but differ (indicated by "!" in context mode of diff, "fct" i.e. replacement in normal mode of diff, and "|" in side by side mode of diff)

Comment: A second question: when comm operates on two sorted files, does it also generate the same result as LCS algorithm applies to the sorted files?

Comment: @Tim if it's not in the LCS (and the line count matches) it differs, results can vary by implementation but comm is just one of many diff views.

Answer (score 1):

> The general problem for a `diff` implementation is to find the next
>   common block of text after it detected a deletion or an insertion.

In order to make the result useful, the implementation needs to decide whether a resync is detected after a single line of common code already or whether there should be more common lines.

The reason for that is that it is possible that an insertion contains a single line that is identical to an already existing line after that insertion. If that single identical line was used to detect a resync, the diff output would flag more than a single insertion and this is not what people expect.

But finding **longest common string** is not the algorithm, it is the problem and there is more than a single solution (algorithm) to solve that problem.

The original algorithm used by the `find` command has been written by Douglas McIllroy in 1974 for UNIX.

Another polular but completely different implementation (using a different algorithm) was written by some people for GNU in the late 1980s.

Both implementations are known to give different results in some cases as the resync algorithm is completely different.

As long as the UNIX `diff` was using the original optimization for smallest code size, the GNU `diff` was faster than UNIX `diff`, but a few years ago, I changed the optimization of the UNIX `diff` implementation to be as fast as possible - regardless of the code size and now the UNIX `diff` is faster than GNU `diff` as long as you use it for typical file sizes.

The algorithm used by Douglas McIllroy is documented at his university home page: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/diff.pdf

> It may be of interest that the inverse to finding diffs is to patch an
>   original file using diff output in order to get the new version of
>   that file.

The first solution of that problem is the program `SCCS` that has been invented by Marc J. Rochkind at Bell Labs in 1972 already, see his explanation http://sccs.sourceforge.net/sccs_invention.html in the sccs home page: http://sccs.sourceforge.net/ and since `sccs` needs diff there have been older but less clever `diff` implementations before 1974.

Note that `SCCS` uses a very clever file format that is called `weave` and that avoids patching files since it allows to have a stream of all possible versions in a single file. Extracting a single arbitrary version from that `weave` file does not result in different times that depend on the release you like to extract - it is always done with the same speed.

Comment: Thanks. (1)   How does diff decide whether a line occurs in both files but differ (in GNU diff, indicated by "!" in context mode of diff, "fct" i.e. replacement in normal mode of diff, and "|" in side by side mode of diff)? (2) when comm operates on two sorted files, does it also generate the same result as LCS algorithm applies to the sorted files?

Comment: The case you mention is when one line is removed and another line is inserted at the same place. BTW: Context diffs are very old, IIRC they go back to a proposal from Larry Wall from the early 1980s. Unified Context diffs use just a slightly different output formata and the `!` is part of that output format. Since finding the largest common sibstring is simple if the lines in the files are sorted, I expect a comparable output.